# how to define id for anchor in codeigniter and use that id in jquery

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

i want to give id to anchor in codeigniter and want to use that id in jquery , can anyone tell how to define id in following code and how to use it with $() of jquery

```
anchor('welcome/remove_rcrd/'.$row['id'], 'delete ', 'id' => 'first')
```

i have found the answer

```
anchor('welcome/remove_rcrd/'.$row['id'], 'delete ', array('id' => 'first'))
```

but this is not working with my jquery ,but using class in same way is doing my work i.e

```
anchor('welcome/remove_rcrd/'.$row['id'], 'delete ', array('class' => 'first'))
```

but dont know how to use id in jquery, i also tried to use id by changing its name but it is not working with jquery but same way with the class it works..... plz tell me what is the problem and thanks in advance .........

Answer (score 0):

as per [documentation](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/url_helper.html) you can use

```
echo anchor('welcome/remove_rcrd/'.$row['id'], 'delete ', 'id="first"');
```

or

```
echo anchor('welcome/remove_rcrd/'.$row['id'], 'delete ', array('id'=>'first'));
```

Comment: it echos fine in my codeigniter proj. i think your jquery selector is wrong. please share the jquery code which uses the element.

Comment: <script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
 
    $('.delete').confirm({text:"Are you sure you want to delete ?"});
        
        
});
</script>  this code works with class but not id as when i use #delete as id in $()

Comment: try `$('#first')` maybe? FYI if you use ID then only the first matched element will be initialized with `confirm`;

Comment: i am saying that i have tried $('#first') also and it doesnt worked for me so i changed the id name to delete it also was not working so when i created class instead of id then it works

Comment: if that is the case then add the rendered html in your question.

Answer (score 0):

You may refer to [documentation(NEW)](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide//helpers/url_helper.html)

echo anchor('news/local/123', 'My News', array('title' => 'The best news!'));

gives :-

```
<a href="http://example.com/index.php/news/local/123" title="The best news!">My News</a>
```

just define the ID attribute to the anchor like this :-

```
echo anchor('news/local/123', 'My News', array('title' => 'The best news!','id'=>'newsId'));
<a href="http://example.com/index.php/news/local/123" title="The best news!" id="newsId">My News</a>
```

Now you just need to grab the values/attribute of the anchor from JQuery.

jquery code : `$('#newsId').val();` if id known.

or use [`attr()`](https://api.jquery.com/attr/) function to get value.